# Expressing Boolean Functions In Terms of Another Function

Tags: computer-architecture, logic, boolean-algebra

Given two boolean functions f1 and f2, are there any tools available that could be used to automate the process to represent f1 in terms of f2? I understand the process of this doing this by hand quite well, however, the process gets quite tedious with more variables. Are there any tools that are readily available online that can handle such tasks?

Comment: This question might require a little more clarification, it sort of depends on what inputs are used. And how you're representing the Boolean function (logic gate circuit, bool algebra, etc...). If you're using a sort of Boolean algebra representation, Wolfram alpha might be able to help. What if for example, f1 and f2 are completely mutually exclusive of one another? Or if they are completely independent of one another.

Comment: @Minko_Minkov My apologies. I meant functions f1 and f2 represented with boolean algebra (A'B' + D'C, etc). The goal is to "share" logic between the two functions to simplify the boolean algebra, if that makes sense.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to specify how f1,f2 are specified/represented, and what it means to "represent f1 in terms of f2" (i.e., what output you are hoping the algorithm/tool to provide - I'm not clear on what that phrase means).  Rather than putting clarifications in the comments, please [edit] the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time and contains all relevant information.